# Python add path of data directory

Tags: python, file, path

I want to add a path to my data directory in python, so that I can read/write files from that directory without including the path to it all the time.

For example I have my working directory at `/user/working` where I am currently working in the file `/user/working/foo.py`. I also have all of my data in the directory `/user/data` where I want to excess the file `/user/data/important_data.csv`.

In `foo.py`, I could now just read the csv with pandas using

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('../data/important_data.csv')
```

which totally works. I just want to know if there is a way to include `/user/data` as a main path for the file so I can just read the file with

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('important_data.csv')
```

The only idea I had was adding the path via `sys.path.append('/user/data')`, which didnt work (I guess it only works for importing modules).

Is anyone able to provide any ideas if this is possible?

PS: My real problem is of course more complex, but this minimal example should be enough to handle my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can use `os.chdir` for this purpose.

```py
import os

os.chdir('/user/data')
```

See https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-os-getcwd-chdir/ for more details.

Comment: But I can only have one path as cwd right?

Comment: Yes. But one thing you might be able to do is set up a symbolic link to one of the folders inside the other folder; see: https://linuxhint.com/symlink-a-directory-in-linux/ (if you're on Mac/Linux)

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Using `os.symlink('/user/data/', 'data')`, I can achieve what I was looking for. Thank you! (Maybe add the `os.symlink` to your answer)

Comment: For completeness, also can be done in Windows: https://www.computerhope.com/mklink.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you are keeping everything in `/user/data`, why not use f-strings to make this easy? You could assign the directory to a variable in a config and then use it in the string like so:

In a config somewhere:

```
data_path = "/user/data"
```

Reading later...

```
df = pd.read_csv(f"{data_path}/important_data.csv")
```

Comment: This works of course, but thats not exactly what I am looking for. I really want the second code block to work. But thanks for the creative input.